# Why is Ibarra Kim for 0/1 knapsack an fully polynomial time approximation scheme (FPTAS)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, approximation, polynomial-time, knapsack-problems

According to one of my CS lectures, there is an fully polynomial time approximation scheme for the [0/1 Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem). A first version was developed by Ibarra and Kim, but there are several improved versions.

Also according to my lecture, an approximation scheme is called *"fully polynomial time approximation scheme (FPTAS)"*, if its run time is polynomial in $1/\epsilon$ and **polynomial in the encoding length** of the instance (usually, the input size is denoted by $n$, such that the encoding length would be $\log n$).

The algorithm has running time $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))+\mathcal{O}(n + (1/\epsilon)^2)$. I do agree on this being polynomial in $1/\epsilon$, but how is it polynomial in the encoding length of $n$?

The part $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n))$ of the run time is due to sorting the list of $n$ items. As far as I'm capable of judging this, this is polynomial in $n$, but not polynomial in $\log n$.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input to 0/1 knapsack is a list of $n$ items each with a weight $w_i$ and value $v_i$ with knapsack size $W$ and maximum value $V$.  Thus the input list has size $O(n (\log W + \log V))$.

So $n \log n$ is polynomial in the input.

The problem with the [traditional dynamic programming solution of knapsack](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28001/dynamic-programming-solution-to-0-1-knapsack-problem) is not that it is exponential in $n$, but that it is polynomial in $W$ (or $V$), which makes it exponential in $\log W$.

Comment: Buzzword: pseudo-polynomial.